# Why do my table columns all shift to the left for instead of being evenly spaced?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm having some trouble with this not running properly. It won't align the text correctly and it also won't distribute the cells across the available space. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any help would be appreciated.

While we're at it, I'm also trying to figure out how to get it to show 2 columns instead of 1 when it switches to mobile sized. The way it's setup now, it just transitions to 1 column.

This is for a website on Shopify that uses an html block to insert custom code. I have other blocks that I've inserted into it and they all seem to be working fine, it's just this one that's giving me issues.

```css
.table2 {
  display: table;
}

.table-row2 {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.icontext {
  display: text;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  float: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .table2,
  .table-row2,
  .table-cell2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: middle;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><center>Materials</center></h1>
<div class="table2">
  <div class="table-row2">
    <div class="table-cell2" width="20%" align="center">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/0ce94db3-8b05-4d84-a64c-dc6de006151c/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Durable
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" width="20%" align="center">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/b6ff1bd5-4c2e-4db0-bacc-3aa76678e92c/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Quick Dry
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" width="20%" align="center">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/e09a4c7e-c262-415f-b491-599bd0bc3a66/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Lightweight
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" width="20%" align="center">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/03df04db-7851-4f80-ad8f-0438cc7e0397/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Breathable
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" width="20%" align="center">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/8034c6ad-6c30-406d-8865-a4bdb4060bca/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Moisture Wicking
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `float: middle` does not exist. You might want to learn `flex` layout and fix your excessive markup. Also `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5, if you're using HTML5.

Comment: Also width and align are deprecated in HTML5 if you use it. Like Kosh wrote, you might want to learn `flex` layout or `grid` layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using flex something like below will fix your issue. There was a few issues with your previous code being out of date. This will also flex on mobiles to show 2 columns as you stated.

```css
.table-row2 {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto ;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.table-cell2 {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2.5%;
}

.icontext {
  padding: 2.5%;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .table2,
  .table-row2,
  .table-cell2 {
// removed all
  }
}
```

```html
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<h1><center>Materials</center></h1>
<div class="table2">
  <div class="table-row2">
    <div class="table-cell2">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/0ce94db3-8b05-4d84-a64c-dc6de006151c/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Durable
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" >
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/b6ff1bd5-4c2e-4db0-bacc-3aa76678e92c/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Quick Dry
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" >
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/e09a4c7e-c262-415f-b491-599bd0bc3a66/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Lightweight
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2" >
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/03df04db-7851-4f80-ad8f-0438cc7e0397/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Breathable
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell2">
      <img src="https://ucarecdn.com/8034c6ad-6c30-406d-8865-a4bdb4060bca/-/format/auto/-/preview/3000x3000/-/quality/lighter/">
<div class="icontext">
Moisture Wicking
</div>
    </div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for the help. I didn't realize my knowledge was outdated. Looks like I have some studying to do.